# Disk space for projects: how do QTP and Watir compare?

Tags: ruby, watir, qtp

Our project currently uses Watir.

The company has some spare QTP licenses, and my boss wants me to investigate the possibility of converting some projects to QTP.

I've heard that QTP projects can use 800 MB per project. Can someone please tell me what a typical space ratio would be for a direct conversion of Watir to QTP?

Please note:  Only replies relating to disk space please. I've seen several other posts relating to learning curve, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watir scripts are just plain text (Ruby) files. I could not say if [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) is the biggest Ruby project (in terms of space consumed) but it is probably one of the biggest. I have cloned it on my machine and the entire Git repository (with all history!) takes 131.4 MB. In my experience, that is pretty big. Watir files in a typical project will rarely need 1 MB. I work on a few open source [projects](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-selenium#links) that have Ruby/Cucumber/Selenium/Watir/page-object code (mostly in tests/browser folder), so feel free to take a look yourself how much space they consume.

Comment: The first 4 files in your `projects` link had sizes of 476, 76, 116, and 686 KB.